# Setting value to a cell on multiple sheets using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Sub Heading_Data()

```
num = 1

Sheets("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3").Select
Range("A" & num).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Branch"
Range("B" & num).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Project"
Range("C" & num).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Customer"
```

End Sub

The above code works fine where in the value of A1, B1 and C1 in each of the three sheets get the values Branch, Project and Customer respectively.

I want to avoid using the Select before setting the values accordingly I modified the code to the following

Sub Heading_Data()

```
num = 1
Sheets("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3").Select

Selection.Range("A" & num).Value = "Branch"
Selection.Range("B" & num).FormulaR1C1 = "Project"
Selection.Range("C" & num).FormulaR1C1 = "Customer"
```

End Sub

The above only set the value on Sheet1 but rest of the two sheets are set with blanks.

Kindly advise the correct way to set the value without using Select.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through those sheets and setting the values for each one is the only solution I can think of.

```
Sub Heading_Data()
   num = 1
   sheetsArray = Array("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3")
   For Each sheetName in sheetsArray
      Sheets(sheetName).Range("A" & num).Value = "Branch"
      Sheets(sheetName).Range("B" & num).FormulaR1C1 = "Project"
      Sheets(sheetName).Range("C" & num).FormulaR1C1 = "Customer"
   Next sheetName
End sub
```